# CakePHP Htaccess 2 Nginx rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, nginx

We're moving a CakePHP Framework installation to a server where there's an Nginx running. Previous server had Apache. This CakePHP has multiple sub-installations on subfolders which all include the /app/webroot/ folder. We've managed to get the index.php working but all the other files located under /app/webroot/ like javascript and CSS don't link up there.

Now, we've tried getting this to work on nginx with multiple different variations. The problem is, the site loads up PHP files and clean URL'S work. Loading CSS and  JS files which are located under /app/webroot/ don't.

We're trying to set up the root to subdomain.example.com where there's an index.php with a header() function to redirect the user to a folder, where there's CakePHP. Basically multiple sites under sub folders. So the CakePHP sites are http://subdomain.example.com/subfolder

Here's the nginx conf we're trying. I've been trying various different options with no effect.

```
server {
    rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    example.com www.example.com subdomain.example.com;

    access_log /home/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/example.com/logs/error.log error;

    root /home/example.com/public_html/;
    index index.php;

    gzip_static on;

    location /subfolder {
            root /home/example.com/public_html/subfolder/;
            index index.php;

            rewrite ^/subfolder/(/.*)$ /app/webroot$1 break;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /subfolder/app/webroot/index.php?$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_comles $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/example.com-php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. `/home/example.com/public_html/cake1/app/webroot/` - first cake, need to be opened as `example.com/cake1/`, `/home/example.com/public_html/cake2/app/webroot/` - second cake, need to be opened as `example.com/cake2/` etc. Is that your folder structure? 

2. Where is images folder, at `/home/example.com/public_html/images/` (and shared between instalations) or `/home/example.com/public_html/cake2/images/` or at `/home/example.com/public_html/cake2/app/webroot/images/`?

Answer (score 1):

app/webroot/ will be your server root. And separate location for process index.php file.

Example:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name yourserver.com;

    root   /web/path/;
    index  index.php;

    location / {
        rewrite ^(/.*)$ /app/webroot$1 break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app/webroot/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your config exactly the same, or you have some other location/rewrite rules? Also you can use `try_files $uri /index.php?$args;` - without `$uri/` if you no need to process index.php in subdirectories.

Comment: It works with your  config, but what I talked about is setting this in a subdirectory, not the subdirectory as the root. Our path is as example.com/folder, our root must be example.com where there's an index.php redirecting anyone to the right folder. Trying to set the root to /web/path/ and then setting location /example { root /web/path/example/app/webroot/; and every other setting just causes the site to loop or not finding the files in app/webroot

Comment: I changed answer, try this. If not - edit your question, please, with more details: folder structure, what you requesting from browser and what php file you want to run.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I spent 3 hours trying to adjust the conf and even asking CakePHP developers on IRC for help but no effect. I adjusted my question and added the nginx conf we're currently running.

Comment: Well.. we actually figured out somewhat of a solution to this by adding symlinks to the subfolder root for js, img, files etc. folders pointing to /app/webroot/folder. The files load fine now.

Comment: The /location block was my issue. Thanks for posting. It helped me in 2019